# How to get the total count of checkboxes of based on particular class

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have get stuck in getting the total number of checkboxes of checked checkboxes when I click select all as code shown below

```
$("#SelctCheckAll").click(function () {
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        var numberOfChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
        var totalCheckboxes = $('input:checkbox').length;
    });
```

So it's working fine. But my doubt is when I add two classes such as class="checkbox1" and class="checkbox2" both having type=checkbox.

For example, class=checkbox1 contains 6 checkboxes and class=checkbox2 contains 10 checkboxes. So how to get total number of checkboxes of class=checkbox1 and vice versa? Sample below

```
<input type="checkbox" id="SelctCheckAll" name="SelctCheckAll">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
```

Comment: `$('input:checkbox.checkbox1:checked').length;` and `$('input:checkbox.checkbox2:checked').length;`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/r4k6z6v0/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use just need to add class name to this statement that you are already using, to get the `checked` checkboxes:

```
$('input.checkbox1:checkbox:checked').length
```

```js
$("#SelctCheckAll").click(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
  var numberOfChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
  var totalCheckboxes = $('input:checkbox').length;

  var checkbox1 = $('input.checkbox1:checkbox:checked').length;
  console.log('Total checkbox1: ' + checkbox1);

  var checkbox2 = $('input.checkbox2:checkbox:checked').length;
  console.log('Total checkbox2: ' + checkbox2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="SelctCheckAll" name="SelctCheckAll">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1">

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
```

Comment: You’re welcome, If it helped you, please [upvote and accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the total number of checked checkbox like:

```
$(input[type="checkbox"]).is(':checked').length;
```

or by using the `class` like:

```
$('.class1').is(':checked').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="SelctCheckAll" name="SelctCheckAll" class="testcheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="testcheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="testcheckbox">
```

```
var count = $('input[type="checkbox"].testcheckbox').length;
alert(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var checkbox1 = $('input.checkbox1:checkbox:checked').length; //for class checkbox1
var checkbox2 = $('input.checkbox2:checkbox:checked').length; //for class checkbox2
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go with a short fiddle:

I used the jQuery `filter()` method to get all the information I need - such as total count of checkboxes with a certain class and also only the checked checkboxes of a certain class.

Have a look at the working fiddle here:

```js
var elems = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

elems.on('click', function(e){
 if(e.target.id === "SelectCheckAll") elems.prop('checked', (elems.prop('checked')) ? true : false );
 getStatistics();
});

function getStatistics(){
 console.log('Total count of ".checkbox1":' + elems.filter( ".checkbox1" ).length);
    console.log('Total count of ".checkbox2":' + elems.filter( ".checkbox2" ).length);
    console.log('Count of checked ".checkbox1":' + elems.filter( ".checkbox1:checked" ).length);
    console.log('Count of checked ".checkbox2":' + elems.filter( ".checkbox2:checked" ).length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="SelectCheckAll" name="SelctCheckAll">

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1">

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">
```